# Error using pointers and dynamic structures

Tags: c

i'm trying lo learn structures and pointers. I am creating a program where i am using a dynamic structure. But i don't understand why my program crash when it runs the "stampa" function. I've read it again and again but i still don't understand where is the error.
Could you please help me? Thanks and sorry for the poor english.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} DATE_T;
typedef struct
{
    DATE_T date;
    int codice;
    int codiceProdotto;
    int n;
} GESTIONE_T;
GESTIONE_T *gestione;
int index = 0;
void add(GESTIONE_T *gestione);
void stampa(GESTIONE_T *gestione);
int main()
{
    printf("1 - Add ");
    add(gestione);
    printf("2 - Printf");
    stampa(gestione);
    return 0;
}
void add(GESTIONE_T *gestione)
{
    gestione = (GESTIONE_T *)malloc((index + 1) * sizeof(GESTIONE_T));
    if (gestione == NULL)
    {
        printf("Errore durante l'allocazione della memoria");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("\nInserisci il tuo codice identificativo: ");
    scanf("%d", &gestione[index].codice);
    printf("\nInserisci il codice del prodotto: ");
    scanf("%d", &gestione[index].codiceProdotto);
    printf("\nInserisci il numero di oggetti venduti: ");
    scanf("%d", &gestione[index].n);
    printf("test 3 : %d", gestione[index].n);
    index++;
    printf("\nInserisci la data nel formato GG/MM/YY: ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",
          &gestione[index].date.day,
          &gestione[index].date.month,
          &gestione[index].date.year);
    return;
}
void stampa(GESTIONE_T *gestione)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++)
        printf("Code: %d - Codice prodotto: %d - Numero: ",
               (gestione + index)->codice,
               (gestione + index)->codiceProdotto /*gestione[0].n)*/);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are passed by value in C, so if you want to pass a pointer as an argument to a function in order to initialize it you'll need to add another level of indirection, i.e.,

```
void assign_pointer(T **p)
{
    /* check p for null */
    *p = malloc(count * sizeof **p);
}
```

You currently attempt to initialize `gestione` in your `add` function, but it only initializes its local copy of the pointer.

Comment: @Tommy4: You can, but since you never initialize it outside of your `add` function you invoke undefined behavior by reading it in `stampa`.  Actually, you invoke undefined behavior in `add` as well when you use `index` to index into your pointer after incrementing it.  You allocate `index + 1` objects (which is to say, 1 object`), so using the index of `index + 1` is invalid.

Comment: Ok, where should i initialize it then?

Comment: @Tommy4: Wherever it makes sense. It certainly doesn't need to be global since all of your functions take a pointer anyway.  The most simple route would be to initialize it in `main` and pass it around.

Comment: Oh my god, it was such a stupid thing. Yeah, i have to initialize at least once in the main function because otherwise there is nothing saved on the memory because it get destroyed after the add function. Thanks again and sorry for the stupid question :D

Comment: @Tommy4: No problem, just make sure you remove that initialization from `add`

Comment: Assignment, rather, not initialization.